# converted to whole number power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

i have a some data from facebook and there is post data like of pages post is like this

```
page             post_message    post_id

k_page            abc      2235104643378942_2279694418919964
k_page           abc        2235104643378942_2279694418919964
m_page           def      2235104643378942_2269253136630759
m_page          xyz         2235104643378942_2268695880019818
```

i did not create these post_id this is autogenerate by facebook power bi when i extract data.. now i want to get total sum of these id against each page when i try this

```
sum(table1[post_id])
```

this shows an error

The function SUM cannot work with values of type String.

i also convert post_id into whole number but this seems like this column did not convert into whole number beacuse of this underscore " _ " .. what should i do ..

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Count post_id? You can *distinctcount* for that. The sum will retrieve an extremely large number that will be far off from the number of posts.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question but I assume you want to group by Page and then how the count the Post grouped by Page 
This was original Data

[image]

and your desired result.
[image]

This what you want or something else.

Comment: you did count on post_id ?

Comment: @MIRROR yep I did

Comment: @MIRROR could you please mark it as solved if it helped you. will help others as well.